# User defined picker view to display 12 digits in it

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I want to use picker view to display 12 digits in it that digit comes dynamic and it has to be light flight schedule display . Digits will be increasing always that i want to make it through picker. As i am new to IOS need your help. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. People here will not write code for you: what have you tried so far (even if it fails)?

Comment: @M.Massias, but Some people will Guide also. Everyone is not as good as we in IT Field.

Comment: @M.Massias i am not expecting the code just an idea as i am new to this iOS.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()<UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

UIPickerView *pickerview = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
pickerview.delegate = self;
pickerview.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:pickerview];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pV didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return 12;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

NSNumber *digit = @(row);
return [digit stringValue];
}

@end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Simple Library and Then Add array of Digits .

here are Few Simple Library , try it once.

> [CPPickerView](https://github.com/cbpowell/CPPickerView)
>
> [ActionSheetPicker-3.0](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0)
>
> [AKPickerView](https://github.com/Akkyie/AKPickerView)

Comment: What's with the all capital letters?

Comment: just pass it to source in Library